# How to make glom work with dict-like objects

Tags: python, glom

Glom (https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is, amongst other things, for

> path-based access for nested structures

**But how do you make it work for nested structures beyond dicts?**

Consider the following class (purposely not an actual `collection.abc.Mapping`, for simplicity:

```py
class MyMap: 
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        """just delegating"""
        v = self.d[k]
        if isinstance(v, (dict, MyMap)):
            return MyMap(v)
        else:
            return v
```

This works:

```py
m = MyMap({'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}})
assert m['a']['b']['c'] == 'd'
```

But this doesn't:

```py
from glom import glom
assert glom(m, 'a.b.c') == 'd'
```

I get the error:
`PathAccessError: could not access 'a', part 0 of Path('a', 'b', 'c'), got error: AttributeError("'MyMap' object has no attribute 'a'")`

**More specifically**, how does one specify:

- what's a node (i.e. an object that can be glommed further)
- a key iterator (how to split a path into keys)
- an item getter (how data is retrieved from a key)

In case it helps, here's the kind of function I'm looking for glom to satisfy:

```py
dot_str_key_iterator = lambda p: p.split('.')
bracket_getter = lambda obj, k: obj[k]

def simple_glom(target, spec, 
                node_types=(dict,), 
                key_iterator=dot_str_key_iterator,
                item_getter=bracket_getter
               ):
    for k in key_iterator(spec):
        target = item_getter(target, k)
        if not isinstance(target, node_types):
            break
    return target
```

This function doesn't have all the bells and whistles, but allows me to do:

```py
m = MyMap({'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}})
simple_glom(m, 'a.b.c', node_types=(MyMap,))
```

Or for an extreme example using all parametrizatons:

```py
from types import FunctionType
from functools import partial

attr_glom = partial(simple_glom, 
                    node_types=(FunctionType, type), 
                    key_iterator=lambda p: p.split('/'), 
                    item_getter=getattr)
assert attr_glom(MyMap, '__getitem__/__doc__') == 'just delegating'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are excellent questions! I'll do my best to break them out one at a time:

### How to specify that an object can be glommed?

When you say "glom" here, I assume you mean "access".

Python features a very rich data model, and while there's *usually* an intuitive meaning for "access" in every context, it can be expensive and risky to guess. glom's approach to this is to [provide explicit registration APIs](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#setup-and-registration).

### How to specify a key iterator?

If you want to split a *path* (e.g., the `'a.b.c'` of `glom(target, 'a.b.c')`) into the structured keys (and operations) used to access that path, I would recommend looking at [the `Path` type](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#glom.Path), specifically, `Path.from_text()` and `path.items()`.

If you'd like to look at an object and ascertain which paths exist within the object, that's trickier.

At the time of writing, `glom` is still primarily designed for accessing and building known structures, with some affordances for defaults/branching. For full context-free iteration of all possible paths, the best I have to offer at the moment is [remap](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iterutils.html#boltons.iterutils.remap) ([cookbook](https://sedimental.org/remap.html)). Note that remap doesn't have glom's plugin/registration power, but it does work out-of-the-box for iterating glommable paths in common Python datatypes, as [this example](https://github.com/mahmoud/apatite/blob/6798619fa7e18b402539b36d1d7a144464c6255c/apatite/cli.py#L554-L558) shows (the corresponding `glom()` call is done just below).

### How to specify how data is retrieved from a key?

I think this is actually addressed in [the registration APIs](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#setup-and-registration) I referenced above. The `get` keyword argument refers to a built-in operation, which must be specified for all types.

On the off chance your definition of "retrieve" conflicts with the built-in `get` registration, you can override it, *or* you can specify a new operation that can be registered against using [`register_op`](https://github.com/mahmoud/glom/blob/master/glom/core.py#L1328), (e.g., how the [`assign`](https://github.com/mahmoud/glom/blob/18e54ebc5163053a2bcee73b3ce18d2ef5af1767/glom/mutation.py#L223) operation was added).

Again, great questions, you're really leveraging Python's power here. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer, glom BDFL. It's sufficient information get what I'm trying to do working. Still, clarification for other readers: By "can be glommed", I meant a non-terminal node. Essentially, defining when an object should be considered "nested" and explored further. Remap (mentioned in the following section) is what I need there. Thanks.

Comment: would you have a link to some cookbook/recipes that involves glom and remap together?

Comment: @thorwhalen Not beyond the case above (yet) :)